# Is a stop-limit sell order executed purely on a first come first served basis?

Tags: stocks, trading, limit-order

The difference between a stop-limit order and a stop or limit order is explained very eloquently in [this response](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/88720/88390):

> Selling is the same, but the directions are opposite. Suppose the
>   stock in the example above has a current price of $46 and you put in a
>   stop-limit sell with a stop price of $41 and a limit of $40. When the
>   stock drops below $41, a limit sell is placed that will sell your
>   stock for at least $40 if possible. If the stock drops below $40
>   before your limit order can be filled (e.g. because there are many
>   other sellers front-running you), then your limit order is not filled
>   until the price comes back to $40.

Suppose 'ABC' stock is currently trading at $46 and I place a stop-limit order with **stop = $42** and **limit = $40**. I would expect my sell order to execute somewhere between $40 - $42. If the stock does not reach $42, my trade will not be executed.

If the stock hits $42, what determines whose trade gets executed first? Is it executed on a first come first served basis? In other words, if  I submitted my stop-limit order on July 1st and Mr. Smith submitted the identical stop-limit order  on July 15th, is my order guaranteed to execute before Mr. Smith?

Can I be confident that if I was the first to submit a stop-limit order within a certain range, it is (virtually) impossible for me to wake up the next day and see the stock price well below my stop-limit order price (as long as someone wants to buy in range of $40 - $42)?

Is there any flaw in this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order matching on major exchanges is done on  price-time priority.

If the price is the same and both the orders are the same type (buy/sell), then whoever has placed the order earlier has the higher priority when the orders are filled.

So yes, your order will execute before Mr. Smith's order **IF** counter parties are available in the $42 to $40 price range.  While  it is guaranteed that your order guaranteed will  execute before Mr. Smith's order, there is no guarantee that your order will be filled:

- Price gaps down from above $42 to below $40
- Other orders have price-time priority over yours and they are being filled as XYZ drops.  By the time your order gets to the front of the line, price has dropped below $40 (a fast market).

Comment: Thanks! Great answer, two quick questions. **1)** Does it matter which broker I use? Or all brokers  get same treatment in terms price-time priority?  **2)** If someone submits a market order (as  appose to stop-limit) at $40 - $42 would it take precedence over my stop-limit? Or once the market reaches $42 my stop-limit becomes a normal market order? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that your order is being entered into the system promptly, it doesn't matter what  broker you use.  Time-price priority is a function of the  exchange.  As for your order, it doesn't become a normal  market order because you have the conditional $40 limit on it.  Here's some discussion which isn't directly relevant to your question but perhaps some of the links may have useful info:
https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/45983/price-time-priority-order-matching-limit-order-starvation

Comment: Thanks! Up voting and accepting this is the answer! BTW, I asked a related questions on SE: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/111760/protecting-onself-from-steep-losses-with-a-stop-limit-sell-order wondering if you have any thoughts..